# How to remove title bar in android?

Tags: android, xml, android-actionbar, titlebar

I want to do android program that contains no title bar. For some reason I cant remove title bar.
I have already tried this coding.

```
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

This one also I have tried but the program suddenly stops..

```
 android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
 android:label="@string/app_name" 
 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

In the Style.xml window (`App->src->main->res->values->styles.xml`)
make changes to the `<resources>` to look like this:

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">

    </style>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 10):

This won't work on Android Studio. You need to edit your AndroidManifest.xml and add this line to the Activity in which you want the window title to be removed:

```
<activity
    ...    
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
    ...
    >
```

If you require the title to be removed on all activities I suggest to pick a title-less App Theme.

Answer (score 4):

try to change

> this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

into

> this.supportrequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

works for me

Answer (score 3):

Several clean and easy ways to remove the title bar in android application. I have tested them in Android Studio 2.1.1

1. if MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity in the MainActivity.java,

   a. you can add two attributes in the activity tag in the AndroidManifest.xml,

   > <activity 
   >       **android:label="@string/app_name"**
   >       **android:theme="@android:style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"**>
   >   ...
   >   </activity>

   b. or you can add a method in the onCreate() of the MainActivity.java file, before setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   > **getSupportActionBar().hide();**
2. if MainActivity extends Activity in the MainActivity.java,

   a. you can add two attributes in the activity tag in the AndroidManifest.xml,

   > <activity 
   >       **android:label="@string/app_name"**
   >       **android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"**>
   >   ...
   >   </activity>

   b. or you can add a method in the onCreate() of the MainActivity.java file, before super.onCreate() and setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   > **requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);**

Answer (score 2):

Please mind that you should call `this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)` before calling `this.setContentView(R.layout.layout_name)`.

Comment: already done that...but I have already solve it..lol...just change the theme in style.xml to no action bar btw thank you..

Answer (score 2):

for keeping Last setting Copy This Code (Android studio) res>Values>Styles.xml

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<!-- Base application theme. -->


<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

</style>
```

if you will need DarTheme Or SomeThing Like That , put Youre Keyword After AppCompact in style tag and in Parent .

Best wishes

Answer (score 2):

I found it better to use "Empty Activity" and put in your app\src\main\res\values\Styles.xml the following config:

```html
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

this will give you an app with no title bar and white background.

Answer (score 0):

In the `styles.xml` file `(App/src/main/res/values/styles.xml)`, make changes to the  to look like this:

**If you find this:**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

**Change it to**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

Answer (score -1):

in AndroidManifest.xml

in  application

call this row ==> `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">`

before this row ==> `activity android:name=".MainActivity"`